# Why don’t I have power to new light fixtures I installed?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have installed two new light fixtures that are on the same breaker; a hallway and bathroom vanity. I simply replaced the outdated ones.
The first one in the hallway worked fine.

Started working in the bathroom. Now, neither of them work 
Everything is connected like it should be. I made sure no connections came undone.

I disconnected the bathroom. The 
hallway doesn’t work.

I turn on the breaker there’s still no electricity being sent to the bathroom or hallway. Is there something I haven’t checked? Did I break my house?

Comment: Make sure to check and reset any GFCI outlets that are in the area.

Comment: I love that input! Unfortunately this bathroom doesn’t have a GFCI which I did buy to replace. However, I’m not sure I want to mess with anything yet anymore! 

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: The GFCI could be in the hall, it could be anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

### The thing about GFCI

GFCI isn't a special kind of socket.  It's a **zone of protection**.   Inside that zone, the current going in and out is monitored.  (electricity flows in loops, that's why every plug has at least 2 prongs).  If the 2 sides of the loop are equal, all is well. If not, current is leaking and could be shocking someone.

Here's an example of a zone.  Some GFCIs are circuit breakers.  The GFCI breaker places *the entire circuit* in its zone of protection.

You're well familiar with the GFCI receptacle.  Obviously, the GFCI socket places the sockets into its zone of protection, I mean duh :)  But actually, on the back of the GFCI receptacle, covered up with a warning tape that says (very roughly) "For Wizards Only", are two special terminals marked LOAD.  They have one purpose: extending the zone of protection to more of the circuit. (And they should never be used, ever, except for that one purpose - that's why the LINE screws take two wires).

So even a GFCI socket somewhere else can protect other stuff - lights, fans, and other sockets.

*Think about it:  That socket in the bathroom must get its power from **somewhere**, right?*  Very likely that place is itself some sort of GFCI device.   That would explain why the bathroom doesn't have a GFCI receptacle if it's already under the protection of a GFCI device somewhere else, it wouldn't need one!

Anyway... I have a sneaking feeling that you changed these lights with the power turned on.  And I have a feeling you touched a neutral wire to ground, or did something to cause imbalanced current to flow, and this tripped a GFCI somewhere.

So you need to go hunting for that GFCI recep, breaker or deadfront that has tripped.